# Google Spreadsheet script reject entries from form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script in Google Spreadsheet to reject form submissions if the answer field is *not* = 12. This is the hopefully screen non-human submissions and decrease on spam submissions through the Google Forms.

In the form I have a text field: Name and text field: Answer with hint "5 + 7 ="

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var answer = "";

  try{
    for(var field in e.namedValues) {
       if (field == 'Answer') {  
          answer = e.namedValues[field].toString();  

         if ( Answer !== 12) {  // check to make sure input is 12

           throw "not the right answer";  // throw an exception with the error message
         }
       }  //end if 
    }//end for 

  } catch(e) {
    throw "try failed";
  } //end try
}
```

After saving this script, I then created a trigger to run myFunction | From Spreadsheet | On form submit. 
Once this was in place, I tried it on the live form, Bob | 13 and the entry still appears in the spreadsheet.

Any suggestions why this is not working?

Comment: `Answer` and `answer` are different variable names...Javascript is case sensitive. Also, the `throw "try failed";` in the catch block should read `throw e;` That way you aren't just throwing another error over the first one.

Answer (score 0):

At this time it is not possible to reject or modify submissions to the standard form that comes with spreadsheets. You would need to filter out unwanted data after the submission.

The only way to modify submissions would be to create a form via the UiApp or HtmlService and running your javascript against that.